# JSON and JSONParser Error -- Register and Login

Tags: android, json

I just finished adding in a AsyncTask to my RegisterActivity.java and LoginActivity.java to help deal with a ANR error, which has seemed to work. Now, when I run the code I get a JSON and JSONParser error. I get this error when I tap the "Register" or "Login" button on my user login interface. Here is the LogCat:

```
09-04 18:13:39.776: E/JSON(854): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"n  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">n<head>n<title>Object not found!</title>n<link rev="made" href="mailto:postmaster@localhost" />n<style type="text/css"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/ n    body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; }n    a:link { color: #0000CC; }n    p, address {margin-left: 3em;}n    span {font-size: smaller;}n/*]]>*/--></style>n</head>nn<body>n<h1>Object not found!</h1>n<p>nnn    The requested URL was not found on this server.nn  nn    If you entered the URL manually please check yourn    spelling and try again.nn  nn</p>n<p>nIf you think this is a server error, please contactnthe <a href="mailto:postmaster@localhost">webmaster</a>.nn</p>nn<h2>Error 404</h2>n<address>n  <a href="/">10.0.2.2</a><br />n  <span>Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4</span>n</address>n</body>n</html>nn
09-04 18:13:39.776: E/JSON Parser(854): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
09-04 18:13:39.786: E/LoginTask(854): No login response was received
```

I am using PHP and connecting to a local server (phpmyadmin) to hold my database values (i.e. username, password, email, ect.) I am using XAMPP, and I made sure that both Apache and MySQL were running. I am connecting my Android to the database via phpmyadmin by php API classes as in this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/
Any help would be appericated. Thanks!

Comment: If there is not enough information please let me know and if you need to see any more coding let me know as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Read the error, fix the error.

The URL you are attempting to read from is not sending you JSON data, it is sending you an error web page (and probably a 404 response code) with text in it like `The requested URL was not found on this server`

Comment: Ok. What I am confused about is I am not quite sure where that URL I am trying to read from is... I should have all the correct coding. Is there any way I could find out where this error is coming from?

Comment: When you click the Register or Login button you must have a handler there to make a request. That should specify the URL that the request is to.